# Is it ok to add a new harddisk with existing data onto an ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a hard drive dedicated to a specific media folder on my Host Window PC and wondering is it ok to just put it onto the Ubuntu server... Or would it be better to just get a new drive and transfer over the files?

Comment: I have shared drives that are formatted as NTFS, and they work just fine.  No data loss or corruption between them.

Comment: Your answer is 3 characters : y-e-s . . .

Comment: Thanks guys... I got a second problem now... I've installed the new hard disk onto the server and set the folder to be shared, but I seem to not have permission to access the shared folder from windows... I've already set permission to read and write and for guest access...

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse you can do that there is no issue at all. In fact some of the folks even share the swap partition between Linux and Windows.
As you can see in my Ubuntu Desktop - I have two drives(one i added later). Both the hard drives have Windows as well Linux.
[image: frist hard drive]

[image: second hard drive]

And this is how they look(appear) in the sidebar of Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3
[image] with the exact Volume label of Windows. You can access them right from there.